# Passing array to function with generic data type argument

Tags: java, generics

Why does this work

```
public E a;
public MySortedArray(E asdf){
    a = asdf;
}
```

and this doesn't?

```
public E[] a;
public MySortedArray(E[] asdf){
    a = asdf;
}
```

How can I achieve the second when let's say I do

```
    MySortedArray<Integer> test = new MySortedArray<>(integersArray);
```

Comment: What is `integersArray`?  A `Integer[]`?  A `int[]`?

Comment: See [Restrictions on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html) in the Java Tutorial. For the second, you should use `List<E>` instead of `E[]` and use the `List` API instead of array subscripting.

Comment: @TedHopp I don't think that this involves the creation of a generic array as in your "duplicate of"; just the passing of an array to a generic class.

Comment: @TedHopp I thought as well, but we are restricted from doing so.

Comment: Both work fine for me.

Comment: I have voted to re-open the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does support boxing `int` to `Integer`, but not boxing arrays of those numeric types, e.g. it won't box `int[]` to `Integer[]`.

You must convert the `int[]` to an `Integer[]` yourself before passing it to your `MySortedArray<Integer>` instance.

Comment: thanks! I still need to practice on Generics, as I always avoided them even in advanced projects.

Comment: May the `? extends Force` be with you.